"I can only imagine" "I can't even imagine" Are the two interchangeable?

I can only imagine why he did that. (=I don't understand why he did that.)

I can't even imagine why he did that. (=A total shock)


Are my interpretations inside the parentheses correct?
Is it just the degree of being upset (the former being low) that's different?
I'm confused about whether the two are actually very similar despite the fact the one is a negation and the other isn't.

I would say that it's the degree of improbability of his actions. The first one: you have to guess his motive because it isn't obvious. The second: his action is so extraordinary that you can't even guess why he would do it.

See also, ELL on I can only imagine, ELL on ways you can't imagine, and ELU on I can't imagine why. I don't think there's a strong difference, although 1 maybe ranges from unusual to very improbable while 2 is more on the side of very improbable. But maybe not always.

"I can't imagine" isn't usually used for things that actually happened, it's mostly for future things you think are very unlikely. E.g. "I can't imagine anyone voting to kill babies."


Cambridge
imagine: to form or have a mental picture or idea of something

"I can only imagine why he did that."
This implies that I cannot easily and rationally understand why he did it. It is beyond reason and I can only offer guesswork and fantasy (i.e. speculative mental pictures from my imagination) as to his reasons.
This is consistent with your own suggestion that I don't understand (but I can speculate).
"I can't even imagine why he did that"
This implies that I cannot form a mental picture as to why he did it. It is beyond reason and also beyond imagination. I can't even speculate about his reasons. I have total incomprehension.
This is not synonymous with your total shock notion.
Shock implies many things other than incomprehension but is particularly indicative of surprise or suddenness:

Cambridge
(the emotional or physical reaction to) a sudden, unexpected, and usually unpleasant event or experience

I suggest that there is indeed a degree to this: the second states a greater degree of incomprehension than the first. But the degree does not necessarily relate to being upset. It may relate to pleasure (for example, if what he did was astonishingly generous or excessively selfless)

Does "It's hard to imagine ..." split the difference?
